# Good textbooks on xVA

Tags: xva

I am looking for some good textbook to understand xVA and related calculations. Can you please suggest few?

Your pointer will be highly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Comment: Jon Gregory’s the XVA challenge is very readable

Comment: Andrew Green’s XVA book is good too. (Jon’a books are the best though when it comes to readability and insight, as Magic said. Plus he provides a bunch of readable spreadsheets demonstrating main concepts.)

Comment: what does xVA mean

Comment: @develarist VA stands for Valuation Adjustment. X can stand for any cost/benefit that standard derivative ‘pricing’ misses: C from counterparty credit, F from funding, M from margin, K from capital etc. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XVA

Comment: Are these books useful to calculate Wrong way risk?

Comment: @user48282 Yes, they cover Wrong-Way and Right-Way Risks for CVA.

Comment: I'm reading these books but I can't understand to model WWR using copula. Do you have other references? I'm working in Matlab.

Comment: For WWR I recall looking at "Counterparty Credit Risk, Collateral and Funding: With Pricing Cases for All Asset Classes" by Brigo, Morini, Pallavicini.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the good books already mentioned, I suggest:

Eduardo Canabarro. Counterparty Credit Risk. Risk Books (2010)

Giovanni Cesari, John Aquilina, Niels Charpillon, Zlatko Filipovic, Gordon Lee, Ion Manda. Modelling, Pricing, and Hedging Counterparty Credit Exposure: A Technical Guide. Springer Finance (2009).

Dongsheng Lu. The XVA of Financial Derivatives: CVA, DVA and FVA Explained (2015)

Recent article Lixin Wu, Dawei Zhang. xVA-Definition, Evaluation and Risk Management (2020) DOI: 10.1142/S0219024920500065

Answer (score 0):

I found the following article on XVA:

[Everything You Always Wanted to Know About XVA Model Risk but Were Afraid to Ask](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.10377.pdf)

It is not a textbook but maybe you will find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This Derivatives Pricing and Exposures Modelling by Lilan Li. [https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B09KN4HD15](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09KN4HD15)